# Query tables imported via Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, activerecord, rubygems

I have this gem (active_nutrition) that has basically imported a bunch of tables into my database. The gem comes with methods and such for getting the information from the imported tables easily.

However, I now want to query for some info from those tables, but because it's a gem, I can't seem to query.

For example,

`ClassName.all()` would give me the error

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'all' for ActiveNutrition::Objects::ClassName:Class`

So, is it possible to query despite the tables coming from the gem?

EDIT:

The class from the gem looks like this:

```
    module ActiveNutrition
       module Models
         class ClassName < ActiveRecord::base
```

Also, the specific query I made was `Weight.all()`

EDIT:

I think I figured it out. I don't think rails likes composite ID's, which is what the `Weight` table in particular uses. All of the other tables have their own ID's, so I can query with them just fine.

So, all of the other tables appear as models, but `Weight` appears as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Any class that extends `ActiveRecord::Base` can use the method `all`, `find`, and others.

I advise you to look into the source - the [the following classes](https://github.com/forrager/active_nutrition/tree/master/lib/active_nutrition/models) extends ActiveRecord. So maybe you are querying the wrong class?

Answer (score 0):

The classes that are part of this gem most likely do not extend from ActiveRecord.  You can simply make your own models that will sit on top of those tables and then use those models to make your queries